# Starring any message in the C++ room makes list of starred and pinned messages disappear

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, chat-stars

[Just now](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/690670#690670), whenever someone stars any message in the C++ room, the list of starred and pinned messages disappears.

This seems to happen across all browsers for all currently active participants in the [C++ room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec).

None of us is in any other room, so we don't know whether this is all across chat.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason (yet to be determined) the clock on the database server was ~20 minutes off. Since the sorting of the starred messages is based on the hacker news hotness algorithm, which as a factor includes *the message age raised to a fractional power*, to be precise:

```
(age in minutes + 2) ^ 1.5
```

the database threw a floating point error when the message had a "negative age" due to the clock being wrong (raising to a non-integer power only works for non-negative bases).

Comment: Hey! Keep your [math](http://math.stackexchange.com) nonsense off my meta. Unicorns here, numbers there