# Random Log Out from chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

This is a weird problem that is hard to reproduce.

I leave my computer on pretty much 24x7 and I am logged in to chat all the time. Randomly, every few days, when I try to upload a picture, the upload starts but instead of submitting the picture, it logs me out.

I can't easily reproduce and it is at complete random, but it has probably happened around 15 times since I started using chat.

Just now was one example, I wrote some text (fine), uploaded a picture (fine), then I uploaded another picture to be straight after and it changed to the grey box at the bottom saying I need to be logged in.

Today was easy, I clicked the link, got the notification at the top saying I am in and I went back... other times it doesn't log me in and I have to clear cookies and do the usual mucking around.

Sorry I can't be more help in diagnosing, but as I said, it is very random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by the clock on the database server being off after a reboot, and the time synchronization not working ([again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90497/starring-any-message-in-the-c-room-makes-list-of-starred-and-pinned-messages-di/90509#90509) – this seems to be some sort of [running gag](https://serverfault.com/questions/1406/windows-server-unable-to-synchronize-ntp-time-reliably)).

The clocks of the DB server and the web server being far out of sync caused updated session information to be out-of-date immediately, so chances were high that your authentication cookie was considered invalid in certain cases.

The chance was even higher if you had a longer-running request, which is why this often happened after uploading an image (which naturally takes longer than a "Has anybody said anything?" poll).

After I manually set the clocks to roughly match each other, the random logouts stopped; in the meantime, the automatic synchronization has also been repaired.

Comment: Sounds like a tricky problem! Anyway, Well done! :)